# QuickBlox iOS WebRTC - audioCategoryOptions Not Found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, quickblox

I am getting the following error with the most up to date version of the QuickBlox iOS WebRTC Framework:

Property ‘audioCategoryOptions’ not found on object type of QBRTCSession

I am trying to default the audio to come through on the speaker:

```
self.session.audioCategoryOptions = AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker;
```

But I receive the error. Any suggestions?

Comment: Today the new version of WebRTC SDK will be released. Wait for the update

Comment: using the new update, I now get the error: 'use of undeclared identifier 'QBSoundRouter'

Answer (score 0):

Please check the code bellow:

```
//Audio Session Initialization
[[QBRTCAudioSession instance] initializeWithConfigurationBlock:^(QBRTCAudioSessionConfiguration *configuration) {
    // adding blutetooth support
    configuration.categoryOptions |= AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth;
    configuration.categoryOptions |= AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetoothA2DP;

    // adding airplay support
    configuration.categoryOptions |= AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowAirPlay;

    if (_session.conferenceType == QBRTCConferenceTypeVideo) {
        // setting mode to video chat to enable airplay audio and speaker only
        configuration.mode = AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat;
    }
}];
```

after that you should set current output device, for example:

```
[QBRTCAudioSession instance].currentAudioDevice = QBRTCAudioDeviceSpeaker;
```

EDIT:

Version of Quickblox-WebRTC - 2.3.1

[Audio Session Documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Audio_Session_.28Previously_Sound_Router.29)